# Pyspark app in bluemix

Tags: python, flask, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, pyspark

So I've been trying to create a simple Flask app that uses spark through IBM Bluemix. The python script looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
import os

from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local')

app = Flask(__name__)

sc = SparkContext('local')

port = int(os.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT'))

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    lines = sc.textFile("Input.txt")
    return 'Hello World!' + str(lines.count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

The requirements file specifies Flask as a prerequisite of my application. And then, the Procfile contains the following command to launch my application:

```
web: pyspark hello.py
```

However, whenever I try to deploy my application in bluemix, the app won't start. I know that Spark is already a service in bluemix, so I shouldn't have to install anything in order to get a spark app running. However, I don't know which command should I use in the Procfile in order to get my app working, which I guess is the cause of the problem since the script works fine whenever I remove the spark code and execute it as normal python application through **python hello.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Spark service documentation [1] ,

> For the BETA, the Analytics for Apache Spark service can only be used
>   as part of the Spark IPython Boilerplate.

[1] http://spark-service-attr-yp.ng.bluemix.net/spark_service_attr/documentation.html

Comment: Does this mean that the only way I can create my app with pyspark is by using Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!